# How do I filter algolia with multiple currencies

Tags: algolia

I have a following case. I have a workers' database. Each worker is addded to algolia with expected salary which he put in. We would like to add currencies. So e.g. worker puts in that his expected salary is `10'000 EUR`, which let's say on the day he fills out the form equals `10'000` USD. So rate is 1:1 so I put in algolia that his expected salary is `10'000` USD and currency of `EUR`. But then when someone looks for a worker in `9'000 - 11'000` USD price range, so it shows him that worker, however in the mean time conversion rate drastically changed let's say `1EUR = 0.5USD`, so his expected salary would be now 5000eur.

So the question is: Is there a way to implement different currencies and let the worker only input his expected salary in his currency however to search in any other currency with current conversion rate? Giving the above example I would need to search for a worker with range including `5'000 USD`.